# Combination of partial derivatives equal zero implies each derivative is zero.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm reading Krantz and Simmons' book about ODE. In 1.5. when constructing the solutions for Exact Equation, they wrote this
[image]

Where (as I'm understanding) $f$ is a multivariable function and $y$ is a function of $x$, i.e., $y=y(x)$.

I'm not sure whether or not I understand this correctly and
I'm a bit confused about how they obtain $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \equiv 0$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \equiv 0$ from (1.20).

*Edit* (Sorry I forgot to include what I've try)

I used the method that is similar to finding a protential function of a conservative vector field, namely letting $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = g_1(x)+h_1(y)$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = g_2(y)+h_2(x)$. Substitute these into (1.20), then integrate one of them and compare to find a formula for $f$. But I'm feel stuck and confuse because $y$ is a function of $x$.

Can someone please elaborate these things for me or give me some hints. Any help will be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since the differentials $\mathrm dx$ and $\mathrm dy$ are linearly independent, you have $f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx+g(x,y)\,\mathrm dy=0$ if and only if $f(x,y)=g(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Can you give me some hints to show that $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$ are linearly independent?

Comment: That depends a lot upon how differentials were defined in your textbook, and I don't have access to it.